# Converting [UInt32] -> [UInt8] -> [[UInt8]]

Tags: performance, array, converting, swift, cryptography

I am trying to speed up my current implementation of a function that converts `[UInt32]` to a `[UInt8]` which in turn is split up into `[[UInt8]]` with 6 arrays at each index.

```
extension Array {
    func splitBy(subSize: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return 0.stride(to: self.count, by: subSize).map { startIndex in
        let endIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(subSize, limit: self.count)
        return Array(self[startIndex ..< endIndex])
    }
  }
}



func convertWordToBytes(fullW : [UInt32]) -> [[UInt8]] {
    var combined8 = [UInt8]()

    //Convert 17 [UInt32] to 68 [UInt8]
    for i in 0...16{
        _ = 24.stride(through: 0, by: -8).map {
            combined8.append(UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: fullW[i] >> UInt32($0)))
        }
    }

    //Split [UInt8] to [[UInt8]] with 6 values at each index.
    let combined48 = combined8.splitBy(6) 

    return combined48
}
```

This function will be iterated millions of times in my program and its speed is a huge burden. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is this part of a [tag:base64] encoding routine?